# Using a non-pandas approach to fill in data

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a for-loop using the `df.iterrows()` functionality. While it works great for a small trial dataset, I am getting some performance issues. Is there a way to have this same functionality without having to rely on Pandas and do in native Python?

What this function does is imports a package (for the sake of example, it could be any package) then looks at `x` column and goes through each row in it. If it is `None`, then it'll use the value from column `z` (in the same row) to feed into the the package and return the `result`. The value of column `x` then gets updated with the `result`.

```
def fillinFunc(source):
    from external_package import externalpkg
    externalpkg = SearchEngine() 
    for i, j in source.iterrows():
        if j['x'] is None:
            result = externalpkg(j['z']) 
            source.at[i, 'x'] = result.fillval
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged pandas when you are looking for a non-pandas solution?

Comment: @It_is_Chris but the OP uses `df.iterrows`

Comment: @It_is_Chris Figured that knowledge in Pandas would help in understanding

Comment: The best solution would be to actually use pandas (not using the loop) since this is what it is designed for. If you don't want to use any external package, then there is no esxape from using a loop (which seems to be causing performance issues here).